# Protractor - PageObjectModel - how to use a var defined in one page to other pages

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor to test an mobile app. I have defined an variables and functions in one page. Now I want to use these variables and function in different pages without declaring again.

Kindly advice.

e.g: var clickhome; is defined in homepage.js. and function to do assert using expect. need to use this across different pages in login.js, homepage.js, diffpage.js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your question is asking how to share variables across files? This is a general js question. What you need to do is share them as properties of the page object.

See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md#with-pageobjects for examples of page objects. In particular, look at how `greeting` is being shared.